# View in laravel error undefined variable

Tags: php, laravel

I am a newbie in laravel and php. I cannot show the results of query in laravel. I wrote this in my program.

routes.php

```
Route::get('books/see', function()
{
    return View::make('books.absen');

});

Route::post('books/absen','BookController@absen');
```

BookController.php

```
public function absen()
{
    $ruang = Input::get('ruangn');
    $results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT id, name, isbn, ta, tb FROM book WHERE ta = '$ruang'"));

    return Redirect::to('books/see');
}
```

absen.blade.php

```
<select name="ruangn" class="form-control" method="post" action="{{URL::to('books/absen')}}">
                    <?php 
                    for( $i=1; $i<19; $i++ )
                    {
                        ?>
                        <option>
                        <?php echo $i;
                    }
                    ?>
                    </option>
                </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Oke" class="btn btn-info">

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>ISBN</th>
        <th>TA</th>
        <th>TB</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($results as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->isbn}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->ta}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->tb}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And error is Undefined variable: results (View: ...\absen.blade.php) I very tired with this. Help please

Comment: Wow... kudos for creating an SQL injection even if you have a full ORM at your disposition that can automatically take care of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of redirecting, you should render the view in the `absen()` action. When doing the redirect the data you just selected from the db is all gone.

Try this:

```
public function absen()
{
    $ruang = Input::get('ruangn');
    $results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT id, name, isbn, ta, tb FROM book WHERE ta = '$ruang'"));

    return View::make('books/see')->with('results', $results);
}
```

Also you need to check if `$results` exists in your view, since you also want to display it when no results are available

```
@if(isset($results))
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>ISBN</th>
        <th>TA</th>
        <th>TB</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($results as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->isbn}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->ta}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->tb}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
@endif
```

### Attention

André Daniel is very right with his comment. Your code is prone to SQL injection. You should really take a look at Laravels ORM [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) or the [query builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries). At the very minimum, use bindings for parameters:

```
DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT id, name, isbn, ta, tb FROM book WHERE ta = ?"), array($ruang));
```

Here's an example with the query builder (Thanks @AndréDaniel)

```
DB::table("book")->where("ta", $ruang)->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your view with your variable. 
Here is what you should do :


routes.php

```
Route::get('books/see', function()
{
    return View::make('books.absen');

});
Route::post('books/absen','BookController@absen');
```

BookController.php

```
public function absen()
{
    $ruang = Input::get('ruangn');
    $results = DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT id, name, isbn, ta, tb FROM book WHERE ta = '$ruang'"));

   return View::make('books.absen')->with(array('results' => $results)); 
}
```

absen.blade.php

```
<select name="ruangn" class="form-control" method="post" action="{{URL::to('books/absen')}}">
                    <?php 
                    for( $i=1; $i<19; $i++ )
                    {
                        ?>
                        <option>
                        <?php echo $i;
                    }
                    ?>
                    </option>
                </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Oke" class="btn btn-info">

@if(isset($results))
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>ISBN</th>
        <th>TA</th>
        <th>TB</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach ($results as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->isbn}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->ta}}</td>
            <td>{{$value->tb}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
@endif
```

By the way, you should use Laravel form functions [Forms & HTML](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html)